# The best way to feed complex XML to Solr 7.6

Tags: xml, xslt, solr

I am looking for the alternatives to index complex XML in Solr. Until now we use our own clients to process XML before indexing.
In order to simplify it I try to put the whole processing in Solr. 
But none of the approaches seems to be good enough (I need XSLT 2 ):

- DIH + XPathEntityProcessor => XPathEntityProcessor is too light ;)
- DIH + XPathEntityProcessor + xsl => the files are too big
- UpdateRequestHandler + tr-Parameter for xslt-Transformation

Besides that, it looks impossible to put the whole XML-Record with tags in one field.
Are there any other solutions?
Thanks a lot!
Katja

Comment: Usually the existing solution will be preferred, since it's far easier to scale - if you need more processing nodes, you can start several more clients that process data and feed it to Solr. If you move everything inside Solr, you'll be much more limited in how many documents you can produce each second (.. and as you've discovered, handling large, complex XML can be hard inside something not really designed for it)

Comment: Thanks a lot to MatsLindh. I just play with an idee to replace our old clients, which are not too fast :), with a newer one or to put everything in Solr.